# Union data in 2 tables with differ column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables as follows :

- 1st table name `bkq` : at this table I had 6 columns named (etab-guib-nom-swift-data-dev)
- 2nd table name `bkdoscde` at this table I had more than 15 columns but what I need to use are (ETAF-GUIF-ETAE-GUIE-ETAR-GUIR-ETAB-GUIB) all those columns are union with data in the first table column :

  1. named `ETAB` similar data in columns ETAF and  ETAE and ETAR and ETAB at the 2nd table.
  2. named `guib` similar data in columns GUIF and GUIE and GUIR and GUIB at the 2nd table
      
     What I need the union data between the 2 tables that shown between table number 1 columns I said to be similar and table number 2 .

In another way column named (etab) at table 1  having data that used  at columns of table 2  i said begin with (Eta--) and also column named (guib) have the data for column at table 2 begin with (gui--) i need to extract the data from table 1 that is being shown any columns I referred at the 1 st paragraph  .

I need also at same query to show column (nom) and (swift) from table 1 and they are not in the table 2

Comment: could you please edit your question, I think no one is able to understand your question in this format

Comment: Can you please post some sample data? and explain briefly what you are trying to achieve and what have you tried so far? It won't work this way, no one would help you.

Comment: Loose it as much as possible while asking a question so that we can help you more conveniently . .

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you r asking for... please use short,simple sentence to form question. It will be helpful for others also to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, out of the 6 columns in your first table [**bkq**] only two will be involved into the UNION OPERATION viz `etab,guib` since they corresponds to the columns of the second table [**bkdoscde**]

```
e.g. Table BKQ(1st Table)              BKDOSCDE(2nd Table)
              etab                     ETAF
              etab                     ETAE 
              etab                     ETAR 
              etab                     ETAB 
              guib                     GUIF 
              guib                     GUIE 
              guib                     GUIR 
              guib                     GUIB
```

If this understanding of mine is correct, then here you go

```
Select etab,guib,etab,guib,etab,guib,etab,guib From bkq
Union
Select ETAF,GUIF,ETAE,GUIE,ETAR,GUIR,ETAB,GUIB from bkdoscde
```

**Edited**

-- added nom and swift column in the union

```
Select etab,guib,etab,guib,etab,guib,etab,guib,nom,swift From bkq
Union
Select ETAF,GUIF,ETAE,GUIE,ETAR,GUIR,ETAB,GUIB,null,null from bkdoscde
```

Hope this helps

Comment: your query is good but i need also to show coloumn (nom) and (swift) from table 1 and they are not in the table 2

Comment: Check if the edit helped you.